# Post data to Django rest API via emberJS in desired format

Tags: django, ember.js

I have EmberJS using Django REST API, I have few checkboxes which I am using to filter the data based on selection of checkbox.

```html
<label>Certificate</label>
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group-checkbox">
            {{input type="checkbox" checked=certA id="certificate_A"}}
            <label for="certificate_A">A</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-checkbox">
            {{input type="checkbox" checked=certB id="certificate_B"}}
            <label for="certificate_B">B</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-checkbox">
            {{input type="checkbox" checked=certC id="certificate_C"}}
            <label for="certificate_C">C</label>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I am getting below in querystring while calling the API:

.../Search?certificate_A=true&certificate_B=true

But the API needs string array for this parameter and it expects the parameter as mentioned below:

**../Search?*certification=certificate_A&certification=certificate_B***

How can I modify the emberJS code to generate the API request in above shown format?